# Can friends order from my Nooklings' catalog?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've upgraded to T&T Mart, so the Nooklings' store now has a catalog where I can order many of the items I've previously found or purchased.

If my friends visit my town and use my catalog, will they see their items or my items? Can my friends visit to order items I have (but they don't) then have them delivered to their town?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Upon entering the T&T Mart, the visiting player is informed that the kiosk is for local residents only.  They cannot access it at all.